# node.js seek to file position

Tags: node.js, fs

Can someone please clarify what the implied action is with the "position" argument in fs.readSync?

I need to be able to seek to a file position.

Many questions on Stackoverflow over the years and the good answers refer to using the "position" argument.

From node.js.org documentation, the following is stated about "position"

**position is an argument specifying where to begin reading from in the file. If position is null, data will be read from the current file position, and the file position will be updated. If position is an integer, the file position will remain unchanged.**

My question is about the last sentence ...

**If position is an integer, the file position will remain unchanged.**

Does "position" result in a seek to that position or is the argument ignored as my reading suggests it is no longer a meaningful argument?

I'm hoping it's just bad document writing and it actually implements a seek.

Thanks

Update: Still confused:

Based on Mat's comments I thought I understood that by using "position" as non-NULL, that a "SEEK" would be performed first followed by a "READ" at the new file position resulting from the seek.

My confusion and question is based on the error I am now getting.

First assume I have made multiple reads from the file -- then these statements

const buf = Buffer.alloc(Bytes_to_read);

r = fs.readSync(fdR, buf, Wanted_Position_in_File, Bytes_to_read, 0);

What I thought would happen is that the file pointer would be positioned 'Wanted_Position_in_File' bytes from the start of the file from which I would read the next number 'Bytes_to_read' bytes.

I'm getting an error stating that readSync is reading more bytes than what buf has been allocated to hold.

Please unconfuse me.

Update Again - got it figured out -- thanks

Comment: If position is null, position will be updated with current position, else its value is unchanged and used as is for seeking to and then reading from that position.

Comment: So what does that mean - after the read at the new position it returns to the file position before position was NULL?  Documentation is unclear.

Comment: The modification mentioned is about the argument variable `position`. Everything else works as normal, file header is advanced and all. The argument itself is updated only if it is null, ie after a fs.read, position will always have a non null value. that's all what they mean.

Comment: Thanks Mat.  Your second comment makes sense.  The node documentation does not.  I'm just getting into js after 40 years in C.  Maybe I'm use to a different level of documentation to understand.  Thanks again - I'm good now.

Comment: No problem, Wish you all the best with the new adventures.

Comment: Please see my Confused UPDATE in main post.

Comment: Remember that the `...Sync` functions are documented by the normal function, so [the fs.read() documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_read_fd_buffer_offset_length_position_callback) explains exactly what `position` is for. It also explains what `offset` is for, and is _very much not_ the thing you want to be setting to `Wanted_Position_in_File`.

Comment: Mike - I've read THAT documentation multiple times and I consider the documentation very confusing with regard to 'position'.  I have figured it out and position is just the file position to perform the read at.  Why would you suggest NOT to use 'position' -- it's the file seek position wanted?

Comment: Your arguments are in the wrong order. That's what he meant.

Comment: I figured that out - I did not mean to come across rude.